# How to change variables from another Activity?

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

So I have two activities: main with all data and secondary with Preferences. There are two arrays in main activity that I want to have access to from Preferences activity and work with this two arrays. In fact, I need to reset all data in arrays to default. Is there any way to do it?

I've tried to use SharedPreferences because I store all this data in it. I changed values in it from Preferences activity, but data in main activity haven't changed, I guess, because it's not being restarted, just paused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences and [register a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29) and/or update the data in the `onResume()` method of your Activity.

Here's some basic example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // get your SharedPreferences objects
        prefs = ...;
    }

    // This method will be called every time your activty comes to the front
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register a listener to get notified when the preferences change
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // do whatever you need to do to update the data
        updateData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // unregister listener if another activity comes to the front to save battery
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    // this method will be called when some preference changes
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        // do whatever you need to do to update the data
        updateData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example? I can't understand how to do it properly.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer. If you know that the preferences won't change while the activity is active (for example because they can only be changes in another activity and not in some kind of background task), it's enough to just update everything in the onResume() method.